# RaspberryPi C++ app compile issue using OpenCV and Raspicam

Tags: c++, opencv, raspberry-pi

Using the code below, I am trying to create an app in C++ with OpenCV + Raspicam. This app should stream video in real time from the RasPi camera model connected to my Pi to an Xwindow.

I get the following error on compile:

```
videofeed.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
videofeed.cpp:36:37: error: ‘cv::imread’ is not a member of ‘raspicam::RaspiCam_Cv’
```

How do I remedy this?

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/videoio.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include </home/pi/raspicam-0.1.3/src/raspicam_cv.h>

using namespace std; 


int main ( int argc,char **argv ) {

    raspicam::RaspiCam_Cv Camera;
    cv::Mat image;
    int nCount=100;
    //set camera params
    Camera.set( CV_CAP_PROP_FORMAT, CV_8UC1 );
    //Open camera
    cout<<"Opening Camera..."<<endl;
    if (!Camera.open())// if not success, exit program
    {
        cout << "Cannot open the video cam" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

   double dWidth = Camera.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH); //get the width of frames o$
   double dHeight = Camera.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT); //get the height of frame$

    cout << "Frame size : " << dWidth << " x " << dHeight << endl;

   cv::namedWindow("MyVideo",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window called "MyVideo"

    while (1)
    {
        cv::Mat frame;

        bool bSuccess =  Camera.cv::imread(frame);  // get a new frame from camera

         if (!bSuccess) //if not success, break loop
        {
             cout << "Cannot read a frame from video stream" << endl;
              break;
        }

   cv::imshow("MyVideo", frame); //show the frame in "MyVideo" window

        if (cv::waitKey(30) == 27) //wait for 'esc' key press for 30ms. If 'esc' ke$
       {
            cout << "esc key is pressed by user" << endl;
            break; 
       }
    }
    return 0;

}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: See https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=67980&p=497499

Comment: @user1929959 -- thanks, but it's still not working. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`bool bSuccess =  Camera.cv::imread(frame);` is an error,there is no `imread`funciton in `raspicam::RaspiCam_Cv`.If you want grub a frame,you can use function `grub` and than `retrieve` .
For example:

```
Mat img;
camera.grab();
camera.retrieve(img);
```

You can see the declaration:

```
/**
 * Grabs the next frame from video file or capturing device.
 */
bool grab();
/**
*Decodes and returns the grabbed video frame.
 */
void retrieve ( cv::Mat& image );
```

Also ,you can get example in:https://github.com/cedricve/raspicam